# ¿Cómo extraer datos de bloques de texto que puede que no aparezcan?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

Dado este contenido para un archivo de texto:

```
@ID..............AM
@ID.............. AM
ID............... AM
DESCRIPTION...... Transansaction
PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO. 20171211 20171211 20171211 20171211

@ID.............. BPI
@ID.............. BPI
ID............... BPI
DESCRIPTION...... BPI
PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO. 20171211 20171211 20171211 20171211 20171211 20171211

@ID.............. BIN
@ID.............. BIN
ID............... BIN
DESCRIPTION...... INTERNET
PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO.
```

Es decir:

> @ID..............AM
>   @ID.............. AM
>   ID............... **AM**
>   DESCRIPTION...... Transansaction
>   PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO. **20171211**   20171211   20171211   20171211
>
> @ID.............. BPI
>   @ID.............. BPI
>   ID............... **BPI**
>   DESCRIPTION...... BPI
>   PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO. **20171211**   20171211   20171211   20171211   20171211
>                    20171211
>
> @ID.............. BIN
>   @ID.............. BIN
>   ID............... **BIN**
>   DESCRIPTION...... INTERNET
>   PROX.FEC.NEGOCIO.

Precisaría, extraer los datos en negrita.
Yo probé usar esto:

```
CANALES=($(grep -w "ID..............." /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{ print $2}'))
FECHAS=($(grep -w "NEGOCIO" /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{ print $2}'))
```

al imprimirlo obtuve este resultado:

```
AM BPI BIN
20171211 20171211
```

El problema se da en que tengo 3 nombres y 2 fechas, porque hay una fecha que está vacía. Entonces, ¿cómo hago para imprimirla igual aunque sea colocando un "-"? Me gustaría presentar todo en pares, tipo

```
AM: 20171211
BPI: 20171211
BIN: -
```

Se me ocurrió pasar todo a un archivo temporal de texto, y recorrerlo línea por línea. Sé que funcionaría pero sería engorroso, siendo que los datos ya los tengo, debe haber algo para extrer cada dato, aunque sea vacío. ¿Debería recorrer cada vector comprobando vacíos y reemplazando? ¿Cómo hago eso?

Además, no tengo sólo 3 bloques como los que se ven, sino 12, y las fechas faltantes son varias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate que cuando haces

```
CANALES=($(grep -w "ID..............." /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{ print $2}'))
FECHAS=($(grep -w "NEGOCIO" /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{ print $2}'))
```

Básicamente estás leyendo el fichero cada vez para obtener un tipo de valor. El fichero es pequeño, pero no deja de ser matar moscas a cañonazos: ¿por qué leer un fichero múltiples veces si con una sola vez ya lo tienes? Entonces es cuando surge Awk en el horizonte, simbolizando un nuevo día, claro y agradable, en el que con apenas unos caracteres lo tienes todo:

```
$ awk '/^ID/ {id=$NF} /^PROX\.FEC/ {prox=$2; printf "%s: %s\n", id, (prox ? prox : "-")}' fichero
AM: 20171211
BPI: 20171211
BIN: -
```

Por trozos:

- `/^ID/ {id=$NF}`
  cuando una línea empiece por "ID", guarda el último campo.
- `/^PROX\.FEC/ {prox=$2; printf "%s: %s\n", id, (prox ? prox : "-")}`
  cuando una línea empiece por "PROX.FEC", guarda el segundo campo. Finalmente, imprime los dos campos guardados, con el añadido de imprimir "-" en caso de que la línea que empieza por "PROX.FEC" no tenga nada más.

Comment: Excelente! funcionó genial y me viene ideal. Obviamente el archivo es mayor y me iba a causar problemas lo que estaba haciendo, sabía que no era lo mejor pero no sabía cómo arreglarlo. Gracias!

Comment: Consulta adicional. Si meto esto dentro de una variable, al mandar esa variable por echo a un archivo de texto, imprime solo una linea. Sería posible guardar en texto el resultado tal cual del AWK, manteniendo saltos de línea? hice esto:

DATOS=$(awk '/^ID/ {id=$NF} /^PROX\.FEC/ {prox=$2; printf "%s: %s\n ", id, (prox ? prox : "-")}' /tmp/texto.txt)

echo $DATOS > /tmp/texto2.txt

Comment: @Nico.C esto es porque haces `echo $DATOS` y la falta de comillas hace que se pierda el formato. Escribe `echo "$DATOS" > fichero` y todo será bonito.

Comment: Qué cosas tan simples desconozco...muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente modificando esto:

```
FECHAS=($(grep -w "NEGOCIO" /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{ print $2}'))
```

Por:

```
FECHAS=($(grep -w "NEGOCIO" /tmp/texto.txt | awk '{if ($2 == ""){print "-"} else {print $2}}'))
```

Debiera funcionar como esperas, también eventualmente podrías reemplazar `grep` completamente con `awk`.

```
FECHAS=($(awk '/NEGOCIO/ {if ($2 == ""){print "-"} else {print $2}}' /tmp/texto.txt))
```

**Editado**: Como bien acota @fedorqui, la forma más idiomática y de hecho más compacta sería:

```
FECHAS=($(awk '/NEGOCIO/ {print $2 ? $2:"-"}' /tmp/texto.txt))
```

Lo que sí, ten en cuenta que esto requiere que los textos `ID...............` y `NEGOCIO` aparezcan siempre con o sin valor adicional.

Comment: `print $2 ? $2 : "-"` sería la manera awk-idiomática. Fíjate de todos modos que cuando haces `grep | awk`, en 99% de los casos Awk solo ya se valdría solo para hacerlo todo. Referencia canónica: [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: @fedorqui: No lo conocía, acabas de ahorrarme cientos de inútiles golpes de tecla ;)

Comment: @fedorqui: Cierto, un lapsus. corregido..

Comment: Buenas, ante todo muchas gracias por las respuestas.
No lo tengo en casa para probar, lo veré el lunes pero lo encuentro recontra simplificado, genial.

Les comento que no usé AWK, porque en realidad, no sé nada de bash, hace unos días me metí para hacer algo en el laburo, y empecé a hacer un frankenstein de otros scripts, robando una parte de cada uno. Sé que AWK trabaja texto, pero no tengo idea como se usa. De hecho leo ese $NF y los parámetros y no sé que son... me pondré a buscarlos.

El lunes les cuento, mientras si tienen algo para recomendarme al respecto, bienvenido sea!
Abrazo!